# Problem after installing SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR#1

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1, broker, hotfix-rollup

We have a SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 setup running with Oracle 11g as the CM & CD Database. We are publishin JSP pages from the CMS. We recently installed the Hotfix Rollup #1 and are now facing a strange problem when publishing from the CMS. If we rename a page or a binary in the CMS and publish, the files gets updated on the presentation server's file system with the new name however the Content Broker database still has a reference to the old filename which causes all dynamic links to fail.

Kindly advice.

Comment: That sounds like a possible configuration issue - or perhaps the HR wasn't applied in the deployer too? This type of issue would surface if, for instance, your deployer is NOT connecting to the database at all (licensing?). Can you double check that _anything_ in the database actually gets modified (like last publish date)

Comment: Have you contacted Customer Support about this problem, sounds like you are in need of an instant solution and don't have an issue with development/implementation. Keep in mind the community here is always willing to help you, but Customer Support should still be your first point of contact in case of product issues.

Comment: @NunoLinhares I have verified all configuration and to my knowledge all seems ok. I have also applied the HR to the deployer (just 3 jar files to be replaced). Checking the content broker database (ITEMS table) shows that nothing is actually being written to the db. Most recent value of LAST_PUBLISH_DATE shows a date prior to applying the HR.

Comment: @BartKoopman Thanks Bart. Will open a support incident now.

Answer (score 3):

considering that the files are updated in the file system location it sounds that your cd_license might be expired or not present. Can you check if the cd_license is present and valid? You should also be able to confirm this by looking into the cd_core log and verify if it is logging: 'running deployer in limited mode' which will confirm if this is license related or not.